# Equivalent to Vim's regex start and end match (`\zs` and `\ze`)?

Tags: ruby, regex, atom-editor, oniguruma

If I wanted to replace only part of a match with something else in Atom, how would I do that?

A Ruby regex solution would probably work, because Ruby uses a regex engine very much like Oniguruma (which is used by Atom).

I found an [Oniguruma manual](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt) which says `\G` sets a match start position, but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Start of match in ruby is:  \G

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't work with Atom.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Ruby has direct equivalents to `\zs` and `\ze`, but you can use lookahead(`(?=pat)`) and lookbehind(`(?<=pat)`) to mimic their behavior:

```
[1] pry(main)> ('abc'.match /(?<=a)b(?=c)/)
=> #<MatchData "b">
[2] pry(main)> ('bc'.match /(?<=a)b(?=c)/)
=> nil
[3] pry(main)> ('ab'.match /(?<=a)b(?=c)/)
=> nil
```

Unfortunately, Ruby's lookbehind needs the pattern to be of a fixed size(or several alternatives of fixed size) - a limitation Vim's `\zs` does not have.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby once used [Oniguruma](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/) as the regex engine, but it has since switched over to [Onigmo](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo) (a fork of Oniguruma) from Ruby 2.0. Onigmo supports several new constructs, such as conditional construct and routine call (which allows you to write recursive regex).

Direct equivalent to `\zs` is `\K`, which is only supported in Onigmo. Note that `\K` and look-behind are not equivalent.

To demonstrate one of such cases, given the string `aaaa`:

- `a\Ka` has 2 matches starting at index 1, 3, but those matches are found when the engine performs the search at index 0 and 2.
- `(?<=a)a` has 3 matches starting at index 1, 2, 3.

The difference comes from the fact that `\K` (or `\zs`) only modifies the starting index of the group 0 (the text matched by the whole expression). The positions where the engine starts searching for next match are the same as when the same pattern is stripped of all `\K`.

There is no direct equivalent to `\ze`. However, for simple cases where `\ze` is not inside any group, you can mimic the behavior by using a look-ahead, as shown in [Idan Arye's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30386006/1400768). `\ze` is rather similar to look-ahead, since the engine searches for the next match based on the ending index set by `\ze`, rather than the index reached by the pattern after `\ze`.